# RecyclerView Issue

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

## MainActivity.java

> its my main java class

```
package com.example.shikhu.newpractice;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,DisplayList.class));
        }
    });
 }
}
```

## DisplayList.java

```
package com.example.shikhu.newpractice;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DisplayList extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dsiplay_list);

    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(DisplayList.this);
    backgroundTask.execute();
}
}
```

## BackgroundTask.java

```
package com.example.shikhu.newpractice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
 import java.util.ArrayList;


public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Fruit,Void> {

String json_string = "http://192.168.1.18:8081/fruitinfo/get_fruit_details.php";

Context ctx;
Activity activity;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

ArrayList<Fruit> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
public  BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx=ctx;
    activity = (Activity)ctx;
}



@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)activity.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ctx);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


    try{
        URL url = new URL(json_string);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }

        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        String json_string = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

        int count = 0;

        while (count<jsonArray.length())
        {
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            count++;

            Fruit fruit = new Fruit(JO.getString("name"),JO.getInt("calories"),JO.getDouble("fat"));
            publishProgress(fruit);
        }


        Log.d("JSON STRING",json_string);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Fruit... values) {

    arrayList.add(values[0]);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}
}
```

## RecyclerAdapter.java

```
 package com.example.shikhu.newpractice;

 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.util.ArrayList;


 public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

private static final int TYPE_HEAD = 0;
private  static  final int TYPE_LIST = 1;

ArrayList<Fruit> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Fruit> arrayList)
{
    this.arrayList =arrayList;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if (viewType == TYPE_HEAD)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_layout,parent,false);
        RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view,viewType);
        return recyclerViewHolder;
    }
    else if (viewType == TYPE_LIST)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view,viewType);
        return recyclerViewHolder;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (holder.viewType == TYPE_LIST) {
        Fruit fruit = arrayList.get(position);
        holder.Name.setText(fruit.getName());
        holder.Calories.setText(Integer.toString(fruit.getCalories()));
        holder.Fat.setText(Double.toString(fruit.getFat()));
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView Name,Calories,Fat;
    int viewType;
    public RecyclerViewHolder(View v,int viewType)
    {
        super(v);
        if (viewType == TYPE_LIST) {
            Name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            Calories = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.calories);
            Fat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fat);
            this.viewType = TYPE_LIST;
        }else if (viewType == TYPE_HEAD)
        {
            this.viewType = TYPE_HEAD;
        }

    }

    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        if (position==0)

            return TYPE_HEAD;
            return TYPE_LIST;

    }
}
}
```

## Fruit.java

```
package com.example.shikhu.newpractice;

public class Fruit {
private String name;
private int calories;
private Double fat;

public Fruit(String name,int calories,Double fat)
{
    this.setName(name);
    this.setCalories(calories);
    this.setFat(fat);
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public  void setName(String name)
{
    this.name=name;
}

public int getCalories()
{
    return calories;
}
public  void setCalories(int calories)
{
    this.calories=calories;
}

public Double getFat()
{
    return fat;
}
public  void setFat(Double fat)
{
    this.fat=fat;
}
}
```

## Row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="Name"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_weight="0.39" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="79dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Calorie"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/calories"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Fat"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/fat"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

## Header_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="65dp"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="Name"
    android:id="@+id/name1"
    android:layout_weight="0.20"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="79dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Calorie"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/calories1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Fat"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/fat1"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

## activity_display_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".DisplayList">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

## activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.shikhu.newpractice.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Display List"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

## My Output

> i dont know why it is showing text of textview rather the data fetched from database
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/992kE.png)

## PhpScript

```
  <?php
   $host = "localhost";
   $user = "root";
   $pass = "";
   $db = "fruit";

   $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

   $query= "select * from fruit_details;";

   $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
   $response = array();

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
array_push($response,array('name'=>$row[0],'calories'=>$row[1],'fat'=>$row[2        ]));
  }

 mysqli_close($con);

 echo json_encode(array('server_response'=>$response));
 ?>
```

Comment: please help me .i am newbie to android.i dont know why it is show text of textview rathan than data fetched from data base.

Comment: r u sure u r getting the data from database?

Answer (score 1):

Your Adapter always return `TYPE_HEAD` i think this is wrong.

```
 @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return TYPE_HEAD;
    } else {
        return TYPE_LIST;
    }

}
```

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Try like this `if (position==0)
            return TYPE_HEAD;
        else
            return TYPE_LIST;`
show updated answer

Comment: this is not correct, if position == 0, type head is returned, otherwise type list. Notice the if has no brackets, so only the 1st line under the if is relevant if the condition is true. Your syntax change makes things clearer, but its only a refactor, does not change the result.

Comment: @ShikharSingh please replace your `getItemViewType` to default adpter's `getItemViewType` method means override this method please show updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem.

Your method `getItemViewType` is inside your `ViewHolder` class. It needs to be moved to be inside your adapter class. Right now, since your adapter has no `getItemViewType` method, it assumes all view types are 0 (`HEADER`), and so nothing is being bound.

Move this method to your adapter class and all will work :)

**Edit**

Another option which should work for you is to stop using `viewTypes` all together. Since you're using the same `viewHolder` anyway, when you bind the view, instead of checking the `viewType`, check the `position`:

```
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
    RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view, TYPE_LIST);
    return recyclerViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (position > 0) {
        Fruit fruit = arrayList.get(position-1);
        holder.Name.setText(fruit.getName());
        holder.Calories.setText(Integer.toString(fruit.getCalories()));
        holder.Fat.setText(Double.toString(fruit.getFat()));
    } else {
       holder.Name.setText("Name");
       holder.Calories.setText("Calories");
       holder.Fat.setText("Fat");
    }

}
```

So now, all your view types will be of type list. This is fine, because the layout is basically identical, only the values of the `TextViews` changes. Instead of using `viewType`, simply use the `position`. If the position is 0, set the header fields, otherwise, use the `Fruit` data.

I know this is not the solution you wanted - I can't seem to find why the `viewType` implementation doesn't work, however, this solution should give you the result you wanted.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, make sure to add the @Override attribute over the method

Comment: just the bit you corrected - I want to make sure you implemented the correction properly.

Comment: strange, your correction looks good, this should work. Is the result the same? Can you confirm that the data is arriving properly?

Comment: yeah i have pasted the json string in the browser address bar.it is giving me the result but it is not working with app

Comment: sir please tell me the solution

Comment: Okay, this is not exactly a solution, but rather a different way to implement what you're trying to do. Instead of using viewTypes, just bind the views if the position is greater that 0. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## BackgroundTask.Java

```
 package com.example.shikhu.newpractice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Fruit,Void> {

String json_string = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/fruitinfo/get_fruit_details.php";

Context ctx;
Activity activity;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

ArrayList<Fruit> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
public  BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx=ctx;
    activity = (Activity)ctx;
}



@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)activity.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ctx);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


    try{
        URL url = new URL(json_string);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }

        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        String json_string = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

        int count = 0;

        while (count<jsonArray.length())
        {
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            count++;

            Fruit fruit = new Fruit(JO.getString("name"),JO.getInt("calorie"),JO.getDouble("fat"));
            publishProgress(fruit);
        }


        Log.d("JSON STRING",json_string);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Fruit... values) {

    arrayList.add(values[0]);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}
 }
```

## RecyclerAdapter.java

```
  package com.example.shikhu.newpractice;

  import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.util.ArrayList;


 public class RecyclerAdapter extends    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

private static final int TYPE_HEAD = 0;
private  static  final int TYPE_LIST = 1;

ArrayList<Fruit> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Fruit> arrayList)
{
    this.arrayList =arrayList;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if (viewType == TYPE_HEAD)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_layout,parent,false);
        RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view,viewType);
        return recyclerViewHolder;
    }
    else if (viewType == TYPE_LIST)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view,viewType);
        return recyclerViewHolder;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (holder.viewType == TYPE_LIST) {
        Fruit fruit = arrayList.get(position-1);
        holder.Name.setText(fruit.getName());
        holder.Calories.setText(Integer.toString(fruit.getCalories()));
        holder.Fat.setText(Double.toString(fruit.getFat()));
    }

}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size()+1;
}

public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView Name,Calories,Fat;
    int viewType;
    public RecyclerViewHolder(View v,int viewType)
    {
        super(v);
        if (viewType == TYPE_LIST) {
            Name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            Calories = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.calories);
            Fat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fat);
            this.viewType = TYPE_LIST;
        }else if (viewType == TYPE_HEAD)
        {
            this.viewType = TYPE_HEAD;
        }

    }

}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position==0)
        return TYPE_HEAD;
    else
        return TYPE_LIST;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not managing views for header in your view holder and from bind view holder it is everytime getting only header view in return; SO just debug your code and let me know that are you getting TYPE_LIST data view or not. Also make references for header view in View holder and set text to it also.

Comment: However you are referencing id's for TYPE_LIST in RecyclerViewHolder class constructor same do for TYPE_HEADER.